# Woocommerce show price with and without VAT in Single Product Page?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I have one issue that dont can find answer myself. I want to show into [single product page](https://www.queekee.it/negozio/timbri-autoinchiostranti/trodat-mobile-printy-9413-mm-57x21/) next to product price (that is in my case currently showed without VAT), but i want to be shown without VAT and with VAT so my customers can know what they really pay. I searched in stackoverflow for asnwer but dont found thread about that with proper working answer. Can someone to give me points from where to start. I using Woo 3.3.5. I found this code on google, but it seems not working properly:

```
function edit_price_display() {
$product = new WC_Product( get_the_ID() );
$price = $product->price;

$price_incl_tax = $price + round($price * ( 21 / 100 ), 2);

$price_incl_tax = number_format($price_incl_tax, 2, ",", "."); 
$price = number_format($price, 2, ",", "."); 

$display_price = '<span class="price">';
$display_price .= '<span class="amount">€ ' . $price_incl_tax .'<small 
 class="woocommerce-price-suffix"> incl BTW</small></span>';
$display_price .= '<br>';
 class="woocommerce-price-suffix"> excl BTW</small></span>';
$display_price .= '</span>';

echo $display_price;
}

 add_filter('woocommerce_price_html', 'edit_price_display');
```

Comment: https://github.com/Musilda/toret-price-bez-dph check this, it's a plugin, but does what you need ..

Comment: Seems its not working anymore.. Showing me the same prices both times.. Check in link into first post.

Comment: maybe it depends on the configuration. it's czech plugin where VAT is mandatory, so people set the store to show price inc. VAT and the plugin is used for displaying prices without VAT too. if it doesn't work for you, just replace some functions with your function to add VAT (calculations)

Comment: Hm i hope so that someone will post some working functions or something like that.

Comment: ...hmmm, OK .. but that's not how SO works ..